# Pass this to overloaded << operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, this

How can I pass `this` to `operator<<` in c++ class?  Or am I just doing this wrong (likely).

For example, in the following class I just have a loop that repetitively asks for and prints an integer.  However, `cout<<this` just prints the address of the instance, but I would like to use the defined operator overload.

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout; using std::endl; using std::cin;

class C {
  int n;
 public:
  C(int n) : n(n) {};
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const C&);
  void set_n(int i) { n = i; }
  void play() {
    int input;
    while (true) {
      cout << this;
      cin >> input;
      set_n(input);
    }
  }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const C& c) {
  cout << c.n << "\n";
  return os;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  C c = C(1);
  c.play();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while (true)   cout << *this;`

Comment: hint: `this` is a pointer, and acts like such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` is a pointer.  You need

```
cout << *this;
```

Also, your definition of `operator<<` should probably use the parameter `os` rather than always using `cout`.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a pointer. You probably need to dereference it.

```
cout << *this;
```